# scrbook class provides option to divide book in three book parts: prebook, main book and postbook

Tags: books, parts, scrbook

As the title says, in `scrbook` (or was it standard `book` class?) it is possible to divide/separate a book into three different standard parts. Hereby it is possible to declare e.g. different page numbering schemes for each part of those three parts.

As far as I remember, those parts were named `prebook`, `mainbook` and `postbook` or something similar. Unfortunately I do not remember the name of this option.

I thought there was something available like...

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

    \predocument
        Bla
    
    \maindocument
        Bla
    
    \postdocument
        Bla

\end{document}
```

Anybody here knows what I try to determine and can tell me the requested options? :-)

Comment: `\fontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, `\backmatter`.

Comment: @campa: I knew it that StackExchange will rock it! :-) Thank you very much!

Comment: @campa: You can post this as an answer if you want. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All common book-like classes (i.e. `book`, `scrbook` and `memoir`) provide `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`. There are some minor implementation differences but on whole they do the same.